# Google Earth API search by Placemarker Name

Tags: javascript, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am trying to create search box for `Google Earth API` Plugin for javascript
I am able to parse `KMLFile` and load in GE API and now I have to embed search by Placemarker name loaded by KML

Code using Lat & Long

```
var lookAt = ge.createLookAt('');
lookAt.set(point.y, point.x, 600, ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND, 0, 00, 0);
ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
```

Is there any possiblity for `LookAt` using Placemarker Name except using LAT, LONG?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are lots of ways to look at placemarks. The easiest way to do this is if the placemark has and abstract view defined. e.g.

```
if (placemark.getAbstractView()) {
   ge.getView().setAbstractView(placemark.getAbstractView());
}
```

You can also use the various accessors to refer to a placemark. For example if the placemark has an ID you can use getElementById.

```
var placemark = ge.getElementById('MyPlacemark');
if (placemark.getAbstractView()) {
   ge.getView().setAbstractView(placemark.getAbstractView());
}
```

Or else if you are loading KML by its URL, e.g.

```
// loaded via KML
var placemark = ge.getElementByUrl('http://site.com/foo.kml#MyPlacemark');
if (placemark.getAbstractView()) {
   ge.getView().setAbstractView(placemark.getAbstractView());
}
```

If the placemark doesn't have an abstract view you can still use the accessors to find the correct placemark and then extract the geometry from it to create the look at.

```
var placemark = ge.getElementByUrl('http://site.com/foo.kml#MyPlacemark');
var point = placemark.getGeometry();
var lat = point.getLatitude();
var lng = point.getLongitude();
```